# My Dell Latitude freezes upon suspending if libvirtd/virtlogd is running

Tags: suspend, freeze, manjaro, libvirt

I've got a strange problem with my dell Latitude E6530: everytime I put it to suspend mode (closing the lid, as per Power Manager configuration) and the virtualization daemons (`libvirtd` and `virtlogd`) are running the computer goes to suspend but at the last moment when the power led should blur out and in, the computer locks up and doesn't suspend. The screen is still powered, there's no disk activity. I've had this issue a couple of times now. I only know that it does *not* happen when the virtualization daemons are *not* running — no idea whether/why there should be a relation. Everytime I start libvirt services and try to close the lid, the laptop freezes while going to suspend mode. The only way out is to hard power off the beast for the magic Sysreq key doesn't work.

I'm runnig Manjaro 16.0 and Linux kernel 4.4.13-1 with proprietary nVidia drivers. Does anyone have an idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of updates later (now with kernel version 4.4.17-1) and the problem *seems* to have disappeared. I guess that was a bug in the kernel but I'm still not quite sure. Time will tell.